# Why does resetting selected context leave a point on the chart? (and how do I get rid of it?)

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am writing a desktop application using WPF and the MVVM pattern with C#. I have a list of charts I need to have the user look through. I basically created a list of chart ViewModel objects, and an integer index that refers to the one being viewed. There are two commands, increment and decrement, which change the index, and I put the following code overriding the OnPropertyCanged event.

```
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "LoadPointIndex":
                    if (this.ResultsList.Any())
                    {
                        this.SelectedChart = this.Charts[this.LoadPointIndex];
                        this.DecrementCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                        this.IncrementCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Then I simply have the following code in my view

```
<view:Chart DataContext="{Binding SelectedeChart}" />
```

Each chart had an ObservableCollection of KeyValuePairs to bind to and it almost works fine. The problem is, sometimes when I increment or decrement from one view to the other a point "sticks". It is obviously left over from the other chart, I have checked the chart objects and they do not have this extra point on them, and usually if I try going to a different chart and coming back, the point disappears.

Is there a reason for this behavior? Can I get rid of the problem?

**Edit**

I tried putting all of the ChartViewModels in an ObservableCollection, and binding a TabControl's ItemSource to the list, creating a tab for each chart... But I see exactly the same behavior. It is intermittent, but frequent.

Comment: Assuming you're using `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting`, i do not have a "sticky" point problem as described in your post. So the issue is more likely in your `ViewModel` rather than in the `Chart` control itself.

Comment: I have no idea how though, it is a really simple structure and that is really all there is to it. I have checked the view models' data and they do not have the extraneous data in the lists of point. It is definitely a binding issue, and it isn't multithreaded where as this problem happens intermittently, which suggests that multithreading is involved. I am getting around it by putting the list in an ItemsControl and just toggling visibility.

Comment: If you post enough code so people can reproduce the problem, perhaps you could get more help.

Comment: @jstreet I noticed that even when I bind to a list of four or more objects, the Loaded event on my chart view is only called once. It looks like the WPF Toolkit Chart only instantiates once. If that is what you are seeing to then I believe that you have all the relevant code. I really did give as much as I could without creating a test application.